# awk to count and sum total using matching string from file

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to get the total length of each matching string and the count of each match in a file using `awk`.  The matching string in `$5` is the count and the sum of each `$3 - $2` is the total length.  Hopefully the `awk` below is a good start.  Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr1 1266716 1266926 chr1:1266716-1266926 TAS1R3
chr1 1267008 1267328 chr1:1267008-1267328 TAS1R3
chr1 1267394 1268196 chr1:1267394-1268196 TAS1R3
chr1 1268291 1268514 chr1:1268291-1268514 TAS1R3
chr1 1956371 1956503 chr1:1956371-1956503 GABRD
chr1 1956747 1956866 chr1:1956747-1956866 GABRD
chr1 1956947 1957187 chr1:1956947-1957187 GABRD
chr1 1220077 1220196 chr1:1220077-1220196 SCNN1D
```

**desired output**

```
TAS1R3 4 1555
GABRD 3 491
SCNN1D 1 119
```

**awk**

```
awk '{count[$5]++}
END {
  for (word in count)
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,word, count[word]
}' input > count | 
awk 'print $1,$2,$3,$4,word, count[word]
}
{ $6 = $3 - $2 }
1' count.txt > length
```

**edit**

```
SCNN1D 1 119
GABRD 3 240
TAS1R3 4 223
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
awk '{c1[$5]++; c2[$5]+=($3-$2)} 
     END{for (e in c1) print e, c1[e], c2[e]}' input
```

Note that the order of the records may be different than the order in the original file.

Comment: Just know that if the order is the same as the file order -- it is coincidental. Awk arrays are unordered.

Comment: Why write `print e FS c1[e] FS c2[e]` instead of `print e, c1[e], c2[e]`? Why `c2[$5]+=$3; c2[$5]-=$2` instead of `c2[$5]+=($3-$2)`?

Comment: @EdMorton: Just the way it rolled off my keyboard this morning I suppose. Edited...

Answer (score 1):

With *awk*, it's possible to do the entire thing in a single script,
by keeping a running count of both the cumulative length, *and* the number of instances for each word.

Try this (yet untested):

```
awk '{
  offset1=$2; offset2=$3; word=$5
  TotalLength[word]=offset2 - offset1 # or just $3-$2
  count[word]++}
END {
  for (word in count)
    print word, count[word], TotalLength[word]
}' input
```

---

The original script had three errors.

1. The second `awk` chunk had an ambiguous input specification: Reading from pipe *and* a file argument (`count.txt`).  In this case, *awk* cannot decide where to read from.
2. In an `END` section, the numbered fields will only refer to the fields of the *last* line/record read.  This is not what you want.
3. Finally, the second awk script is missing the opening brace `{` for the print statement.

Comment: The `awk` produces the correct count for the matching strings in the file but appears to only be using the last record in the match as the length.... I added the output in the edit.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$5 != prev { if (NR>1) print prev, cnt, sum; prev=$5; cnt=sum=0 }
{ cnt++; sum+=($3-$2) }
END { print prev, cnt, sum }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
TAS1R3 4 1555
GABRD 3 491
SCNN1D 1 119
```

Comment: This only works if the files is block sorted by $5, correct?

Comment: Correct. Hopefully the OP wouldn't show ordered input in his/her example if that's not what they really have.